Dice game, what is probability of winning?
Suppose we are playing a game where we throw a 6-sided dice and I win if it ends up being an even number, the other player wins if its 1 or 3 and the we roll again if its something else. For this my P(win) is as follows:
$P(win)=p=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}p \implies p=\frac{6}{10}$. We change the game and I now win only if two even numbers in a row while all other thing hold true, i.e. the other player wins if they get one 1 or 3. What is now my probability of winning?
I took a similar approach and found that $p=3/8$ but I fear my approach is not correct for the case with two consecutive even numbers is a win.
$p=\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}p \implies p=\frac{3}{10}$. Im unsure if this is the correct answer.

In the case where you only need to roll an even number once, why is your winning probability the solution of the equation $p=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}p$? If you can fully explain your first solution, you should be able to answer your own question about rolling two even numbers.

Important question.  If your rolls are, in order, $5, 2, 4$, have you won, or do you need to roll another even number to win?  In other words, is this equivalent to rolling a pair of dice or can you achieve your victory condition with any two consecutive die rolls?

This was a problem I came up with just to get some more practice so there is not an exact answer but I suppose 5,2,4 would mean you win.

I think you are getting tripped up on the fact that this game can get 'restarted' (in theory) infinitely many times as long as a 5 is rolled.
We'll set this up with a recurrence relation where $P_0$ is our probability of winning when we have had no evens yet and $P_1$ is our probability of winning given we had an even on our last roll.
$$P_0=\frac{1}{2}P_1+\frac{1}{6}P_0$$
$$P_1=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}P_0$$
substituting and rearranging we get
$$P_0=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}P_0)+\frac{1}{6}P_0$$
$$P_0=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{12}P_0+\frac{1}{6}P_0$$
$$P_0=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}P_0$$
$$\frac{3}{4}P_0=\frac{1}{4}$$
$$P_0=\frac{1}{3}$$
